# Implementing Dual Encoder LSTM in Keras with Tensorflow backend

Tags: keras, lstm, tf.keras

[Dual Encoder LSTM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbQgZ.png)

I want to implement this model in TensorFlow Keras API. I am confused about how to implement the sigmoid(CMR) function in Keras. How to merge the output of both LSTM's an compute the above function ?

RNN here means LSTM

C and R are sentences encoded into a fixed dimension by the two LSTM's. Then they are passed through a function sigmoid(CMR). We can assume that R and C are both 256 dimensional matrices and M is a 256 * 256 matrix. The matrix M is learned during training.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only consider the final output of the LSTMs and not the whole sequence, the shape of the output of each LSTM model would be (batch_size, 256).

Now, we have the following vectors and their shapes:

> C: (batch_size, 256)
>
> R: (batch_size, 256)
>
> M: (256, 256).

The simplest case is for `batch_size = 1`. Then,

> C: (1, 256)
>
> R: (1, 256)

So, mathematically, C<sup>T</sup>MR would practically be CMR<sup>T</sup>, and give you a vector of shape (1, 1), which can be represented by any number of dimensions.

In code, this is straightforward:

```
def compute_cmr(c, m, r):
    r = tf.transpose(r, [1, 0])
    output = tf.matmul(c, m)
    output = tf.matmul(output, r)
    return output
```

However, if your `batch_size` is greater than 1, things can get tricky. My approach (using eager execution) is to unstack along the batch axis, process individually, then restack. It may not be the most efficient way, but it works flawlessly and the time overhead usually is negligible.

Here's how you can do it:

```
def compute_cmr(c, m, r):
    outputs = []
    c_list = tf.unstack(c, axis=0)
    r_list = tf.unstack(r, axis=0)
    for batch_number in range(len(c_list)):
        r = tf.expand_dims(r_list[batch_number], axis=1)
        c = tf.expand_dims(c_list[batch_number], axis=0)
        output = tf.matmul(c, m)
        output = tf.matmul(output, r)
        outputs.append(output)
    return tf.stack(outputs, axis=0)
```

Comment: I did not understand how C^TMR would practically be CMR^T. Dimensions dont add up.
Also I want M to be learned during training. How do you suggest I dot that ? 
Do I write some custom layer in Keras ?

Comment: I am thinking of implementing a custom layer in which the input would be C. I would declare a matrix M with shape(input_dim,input_dim) and perform C^T inside that layer and then combine the output of that layer with R to get sigmoid(CMR). Do you think that can work ?

Comment: In equation form C is a row vector and C-transpose is a column vector. However, in practice, a vector of shape (N, 1) is a column vector and (1, N) a row vector.

Comment: The implementation you described is the recommended way to do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Susmit. I had one more small doubt. I would appreciate if you could help out.

As explained above instead of creating a custom layer, what if I just declare a tf.Variable(M,shape,trainable = True). I would then just multiply C^T with the variable M and compute the sigmoid(CMR) function.
I am confused if the variable M will be trained automatically ?
Documentation states that Gradienttape API tracks which variables need gradients.
So is trainable = True enough to tell tensorflow to automatically compute the gradients for variable M ?

Comment: Yes, that will work. But initialize M before the training loop.

Comment: Susmit can you please help me out in another issue ? I cannot explain it in detail in comments section. Below is the link. I'd really appreciate your help.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61434540/how-to-train-a-parameter-outside-the-model

Comment: I implemented the solution adding a custom layer declaring the matrix M with trainable weights. Now I have written a custom training loop applying gradients using GradientTape. For the first 10-15 iterations the predictions are of sigmoid(CMR)  are correct, but after that the predictions become so small that loss = - 0.0
An example of a prediction is tf.Tensor([[4.8197186e-23]].

Can you provide any insights to this ?

Comment: I would really appreciate your help on a new question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61472333/predictions-from-a-model-become-very-small-the-loss-is-either-0-or-a-positive-c

I am stuck on this problem and I have to submit this project next week. Can you please take a look at it.