# How to train a parameter outside the model?

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I am implementing the following architecture in Tensorflow 2.0 [Dual Encoder LSTM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Qf17.png)

C and R are sentences encoded into a fixed dimension by the two LSTM's. Then they are passed through a function sigmoid(CMR). We can assume that R and C are both 256 dimensional matrices and M is a 256 * 256 matrix. The matrix M is learned during training.
Since I want to train M, I declared M = tf.Variable(shape,trainable = True).
But after fitting the model, the values of M are still not changing. How to tell tensorflow to compute the gradients for M automatically ? Below is my code.
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOIur.png)

Comment: You cannot use `model.fit` to train variables outside a model. You will have to use `GradientTape`.

Comment: But as per the documentation, GradientTape automatically tracks all variables which have trainable = True. 
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable

Comment: It tracks variables, but does not compute gradients unless you ask it to. You need to call `tape.gradient(loss, variable)` explicitly.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the clarification :) . I will try that and get back to you in case I have any trouble.